# Unity sounds not playing after returning to previous scene

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I have this class

```
public class MenuSounds : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioClip[] sounds = new AudioClip[1];

    public void PlaySound(int sound)
    {
        Debug.Log("Playing sound");
        Debug.Log("sounds[0]="+sounds[0]);
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(sounds[0],Vector3.zero,1);
        Debug.Log("After sound");
    }
}
```

So the game starts and a main menu opens. There are buttons with Event triggers which run PlaySound(int s). That works fine until I change to other scene (main game) and then return to the Main_Menu scene. 
Tried to debug... everything seems just fine. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Just to check, when you say debugging seems fine, you mean that the logger is showing your functions messages, right?

Comment: yes, it show that "sound[0]" file is what is suppose to be and not null.

Comment: Well, I find workaround: just add Audio Source component to one button and used that with function                                                             public void PlaySound(int button)
 `   {
        buttons[button].GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        
    }`                                                                                                                      from Event Trigger

Comment: Glad you figured out! If you have a working solution you can post it as an answer to your own question, so anyone else who comes across this can see it.